# Why is reference-type parameter passed to function by reference implicitly in C#?

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

So I was learning the Heapsort algorithms and I understood it perfectly. However, when looking at my code I do not actually understand why it works, since in C# if I want to change a value of a parameter by passing it to a function I have to use the ref keyword, otherwise its a value-type parameter which should not change when passed to a function.

```
public static class HeapSort
{
    public static List<int> Sort(List<int> array)
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        int n = array.Count;

        for(int i = n/2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Heapify(array, n, i);
        }

        int sizeOfArray = n;
        while(result.Count != n)
        {
            result.Insert(0, array[0]);
            array[0] = array[sizeOfArray - 1];
            array.RemoveAt(sizeOfArray - 1);
            sizeOfArray--;
            Heapify(array, sizeOfArray, 0);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void Heapify(List<int> array, int n, int i)
    {
        int smallest = i;
        int left = 2 * i + 1;
        int right = 2 * i + 2;

        if(left < n && array[smallest] > array[left])
        {
            smallest = left;
        }

        if(right < n && array[smallest] > array[right])
        {
            smallest = right;
        }

        if(smallest != i)
        {
            int temp = array[smallest];
            array[smallest] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
            Heapify(array, n, smallest);
        }

    }
}
```

I don't understand why calling Heapify without ref works in changing the array.

Comment: Class objects (Like List<int>) are automatically passed by reference.

Comment: You can think of it like "reference types are also passed by value, by value of a reference". It's something different than "by a copy of an object (it's how we usually understand what *value* is" and also different than "by a reference to a reference".

Answer (score 0):

In c# there are [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) types and [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) types. Value types are passed by value unless you pass them with [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword. Reference types are always passed by reference.

For example if you declare two variables like this

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
int myint = 0;
```

`myInt` holds value `0`, but `myList` only holds a reference which points to actual instance of `List<int>`. This means that when you pass `myInt` to a method you just pass a copy of it's value. When you pass `myList` you do the same thing - you pass a copy of its value, but its value is a reference to instance of `List<int>`, so copy of this reference still refers to the same `List<int>` on the heap.

When you pass variable with a `ref` keyword you actually pass a pointer to your original variable. If you pass `myInt` with `ref` keyword your method will receive pointer to `myInt`, so it will be able to modify its actual value. If you pass `myList` with `ref` keyword same thing happens. Now your method can modify actual value of `myList` variable. It can set it to some other reference.

It's probably easier to understand when you see it in practice, so here is small console application showing difference between two methods which differ only by use of `ref` keyword

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //create new instane of List<int> on the heap and store reference to it on the stack in 'myList 'variable
    List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 1 };
    //create new instance of int and store it on the stack in 'myInt' variable
    int myint = 2;

    //call MyMethod
    //copy value of myInt (2) to the new stack frame and store it in 'i' variable
    //copy value of myList (reference to List<int>) to the new stack frame and store it in 'list' variable
    MyMethod(myint, myList);
    Console.WriteLine(myint);       //prints 2
    Console.WriteLine(myList[0]);   //prints 4

    //call MyMethod
    //inside new stack frame store pointer to 'myint' variable
    //inside new stack frame store pointer to 'myList' variable
    MyMethod(ref myint, ref myList);
    Console.WriteLine(myint);       //prints 3
    Console.WriteLine(myList[0]);   //prints 5

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void MyMethod(int i, List<int> list)
{
    //store value of 3 on stack in variable 'i'
    i = 3;
    //use reference stored on stack in 'list' variable to find our instance of List<int> on the heap and store 4 under index 0
    list[0] = 4;
    //create new instane of List<int> on the heap and store reference to it on the stack, in 'list 'variable
    list = new List<int>() { 5 };
}

static void MyMethod(ref int i, ref List<int> list)
{
    //use pointer to 'myInt' variable to store value of 3 in 'myInt' variable
    i = 3;
    //use pointer to 'myList' variable to get reference stored in it and use that reference to find our instance of List<int> on the heap and store 4 under index 0
    list[0] = 4;
    //create new instane of List<int> on the heap and use pointer to 'myList' variable to store reference to that new instance inside 'myList' variable
    list = new List<int>() { 5 };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that ;) I wasn't sure if i can explain it in easy to understand way. If that answers your question then you can accept is as the answer to it